# Contained UITableView's Height always 44.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistackview

I am trying to create a button like UIControl that looks like the standard UITableViewCell and support the CellStyles of Value1, Default and Subtitle.

I did try simply creating a UITableViewCell and adding it as a SubView of my UIControl but unsurprisingly the cells don't behave as expected when not in a UITableView.

So I now have a table in my UIControl that has a custom Table DataSource that is hardcoded to only one row.

When I create the cell I populate the text values of the TextLabel and DetailLabel.

This works fine in most cases but when my UIControl is arranged in a UIStackView it is refusing to size the table/cell's height any greater that 44.0.

I am using the CellStyle SubTitle and setting the Labels to be Multilines. They do wrap but appear outside of the Cell which appears fixed to 44.0.

I have set EstimatedHeight on Table and AutomaticDimension

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why this might be.

Sent from my iPhone

Comment: You really need to rethink this. Using a table view inside a custom control just so you can replicate something like a single cell is pretty inefficient. Write your own custom view that provides the basic cell functionality that you need.

Comment: I had tried that but one of the issues was that (and this might seem minor) the accessory bits aren't available for me to reuse such as the right chevron. Do you know how I can access them?

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell, but a quick google (uitableviewcell default height) indicates 44 is the default height of a cell. I'm assuming you need to set the row height of the uitableview (heightForRowAtIndexPath).